# Google's Messenger app not attach Image while send MMS

Tags: android, android-intent, telephony, mms

I'm unable to send MMS with image on Google's [Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging) app.
While some of the android device by default install this SMS app and for that when I send MMS using `Intent` than  it's not working.

The problem is ToNumber and MMS content set but the image is not attach on this app.

**Note:**
I already set the MMS APN setting on my devices,and i already check on multiple devices with same app like Samsung s4,Motorola G4 Plus.

This is my code currently I Used.

```
 String toNumbers = "comma seperated mobile numbers";

 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) 
    {
        String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(getActivity()); 

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra("address", toNumbers);
        sendIntent.setPackage("com.android.mms");
        //Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(""), "image.png"));

        File imagePath = new File(getFilesDir(), "images");
        File newFile = new File(imagePath, "image.png");
        Uri uri = getUriForFile(this, "packagename", newFile);

        File file = new File(contentUri.getPath());
        if (file.exists()) {
            //Do something
            Log.d("TAG","Exist");
        }
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        sendIntent.setType("image/png");
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", getString(R.string.sms_body, HostName));
        if (defaultSmsPackageName != null)
        {
            sendIntent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
        }
        startActivityForResult(sendIntent, Constants.SEND_SMS_REQUEST);


    }
    else 
    {
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        smsIntent.putExtra("address", toNumbers);
        smsIntent.setPackage("com.android.mms");
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(""), "image.png"));
        smsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        smsIntent.setType("image/png");
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", getString(R.string.sms_body, HostName));
        startActivityForResult(smsIntent, Constants.SEND_SMS_REQUEST);
    }
```

**file_paths.xml**

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<files-path
    name="files"
    path="images/" />

</paths>
```

**manifeast.xml**

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="packagename"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />


    </provider>
```

Comment: `getExternalFilesDir` returns a directory to which only your app has permissions. No other app can read from it. You'll need to expose your file via a [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html).

Comment: I already try with this,but its not working.

Comment: **Well then update the question so we know what you're currently working with.** Are you absolutely sure a) you followed all the steps including granting temporary permissions b) the file path is right? External files dir points most likely to `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<your app's app ID>/files` which is internal storage not SD card.

Comment: yes my files `Uri` is `content://mypackage/files/image.png` and the file is exist also on that path..,but when i programatically try to check exist the file it returns false..some strage issue produce.

Comment: Post your file provider definition XML file. And body of getUriForFile method.

Comment: please show updated question

Comment: `files-path` points to `/data/data/<your-app>/files` which is not externally accessible unless you have a rooted phone. This is not what you see when you connect the phone to your computer. You can use [CWAC-Provider](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) which works very much like `FileProvider` except it supports `external-files-path`.

Comment: is the file you're sharing created by your app?

Answer (score 1):

**file_paths.xml** and **manifest.xml** are the same as in your code.

**Create content uri**:

```
File imagePath = new File(getFilesDir(), "images");
File newFile = new File(imagePath, "image.png");
Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "packagename", newFile);
```

**Check content uri:**

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
//Your image should be displayed
imageView.setImageURI(contentUri);
```

**Create intent:**

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text to send");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
```

**Solution tested on:**

a) Galaxy S4, Android 5.0, Messenger ver: 1.9.036

b) Emulator: Nexus 5, Android 6.0, Messaging ver: 1.0.001